# Les expressions « en être » et « en être à », sont-elles des synonymes l'une de l'autre ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> **En être** + adverbe ou complément, indique la situation, le point d'une évolution : Où en êtes-vous dans votre travail ?
>
> **En être à**, être arrivé au point de : Il en est à demander l'aumône.

Après avoir lu ce que [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre/31549/locution) nous dit concernant ces deux expressions, il me semble qu'elles sont très proches l'une de l'autre sémantiquement, sinon des synonymes parfaits ; et si c'est vrai, comment puis-je les utiliser correctement dans ce que j’écris en français ; comment savoir si je n'aurais pas dû utiliser l'autre expression en lieu et place de celle que j'ai réellement utilisée ?

Comment: +1 I agree with you that they seem nearly, if not perfectly, synonymous, which begs the question why *Larousse* addresses them separately. The biggest difference I see is that the first one seems better suited for asking “Where?” and the second for answering (or declaring) with the requested (or greater) detail/s.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the seeming similarity, they do have two different meanings:

---

The « en être à » signifies a ***transformation***/***change*** from the previous to the current state. For instance, I’d say something like:

> Ça me dépasse que tu **en sois** venu **à** travailler pour quelqu'un comme lui !

---

With the « en être + adverbe », on the other hand, the focus is more on describing the current ***already reached*** state. For example:

> Si elle **en est là** aujourd'hui, c'est parce qu'elle travaille toujours dur !

Comment: That's interesting. You may very well be on to something here, I give you that. I am really interested in knowing more about your "extreme" method of learning languages. Would you mind if I wrote you an email? Maybe we can talk more about languages in private.

Comment: ‘En sois venu à’ c’est pas ‘en être à’ mais plutôt ‘en venir à’, qui, bien-sûr, exprime ce que vous avez écrit.