# Whether to include the pronoun « en » in the phrase « n’en être qu’à ses débuts » ?

Tags: pronoms

I just said the following as a little pep talk:

> Pourquoi t'es si pressée ? Pourquoi tous ces soupirs ? Moi qui croyais que tu étais le porte-parole d'« être toujours optimiste » ? Ta vie professionelle semble **n’en être qu’à ses débuts**.

I wonder in hindsight if I should have left the pronoun « en » out, given the presence of « ses »:

> Ta vie professionelle semble **n’être qu’à ses débuts**.

Using « en » instinctively came to mind, but I cannot shake off the feeling that both « en » and « ses » are overlapping things.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been much easier to understand if you'd written: _Ta vie professionelle semble être (seulement) à ses débuts_?

Comment: Unfortunately, saying "Ta vie professionelle semble **être à ses débuts**" without "ne ... que" takes the edge off the emphasis, while using "**seulement**" instead of "ne ... que" sounds strange to my ears – as if being at the beginning (at what stage) of your career were the only important aspect of it, not taking into account other aspects such as "how **well** you are doing" etc.

Comment: Either way, I don't think _en_ is necessary. Emphasis or no emphasis.

Comment: The *en* is required here and *ses* has nothing to do with it. It's what's described [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25534/358). There's indeed a change when you go from nothing/nowhere to a "beginning". ;-)

Comment: @Laure Hi. The idea that I wanted the "en" to refer to was more like "Ta vie professionelle semble n’être qu’à ses débuts **des choses**", or something like that. What's your take on this? ;)

Comment: @Alone-zee I'm afraid I don't really see what you mean. *choses* wouldn't work here but I suppose you're using it as a wild card, we could have *Ta vie professionelle semble n’ (en) être qu’au début de son existence*, so with an optional *en*. But I don't know if it's anywhere near what you're asking...

Comment: @Laure Indeed, I meant "choses" as a *wild card*. ;)

Comment: @Alone-zee I get what you're trying to say and i think it's the right way to see "en". With, your sentence feels complete, over. Without, it almost seems like you're about to add something. But i think that the one with "en" fits more in the whole text.

Comment: Voir aussi au TLFi à [être](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) à "Cas partic. de être de avec pron. adv. : en être". 2e sect. I B 6 e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« en » and « ses » do not overlap, here.

« en être » is (among other uses) commonly used to imply **progression**. For example, « T’es où ? » means “Where are you?” (physical location), whereas « T’en es où ? » roughly means “How much did you progress?” (on a task implied by the context).

Here, you’re referring to the progression of your interlocutor’s professional life, not to its location, so « en » seems adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que la formulation "originale" de l'expression (qui est aujourd'hui figée) est quelque chose comme "ce n'est que le début de X", qui inclut bel et bien un complément en *de* qui devient le pronom *en* dès lors que l'on réorganise la phrase pour faire de X le sujet.

Je ne peux pas vraiment élaborer plus car mon ouvrage de référence habituel (Grevisse, Bon Usage, 14e éd.) ne parle pas de cette construction. Si ça vous intéresse, les usages de *en* pronom sont couvert sous la section §676.