# Pourquoi le « en » à « t'en es où » ?

Tags: pronoms, en

Pourquoi dit-on « t'en es où (avec un projet) ? »" plutôt que « tu es où (avec un projet) » ?

C'est-à-dire, pourquoi le "en" ?

Je comprends que "en" soit utilisé quand le verbe est suivi de la préposition "de", mais dans ce cas on ne dirait pas « Je suis *de* les premières préparations avec mon projet », alors je ne sais pas d'où vient ce "en".

Comment: Est-ce que ça répond à la question ? https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25533/les-expressions-en-%C3%AAtre-et-en-%C3%AAtre-%C3%A0-sont-elles-des-synonymes-lune-de

Comment: "https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25533/les-expressions-en-%C3%AAtre-et-en-%C3%AAtre-%C3%A0-sont-elles-des-synonymes-lune-de" does not cover the present question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On dit seulement « Tu en es où de ton projet ? », jamais  « … avec … ? », ce qui est un anglicisme. La préposition correcte pour le français est « de ».  « T'en es où (**de** ton projet) ? » est familier ; on dit aussi « Où tu en es (**de** ton projet) ? » (familier) et  (standard) « Où en es-tu  (**de** ton projet) ? ».

On peut maintenant s'interroger sur la raison de l'utilisation de « en ». Je ne trouve pas d'explication dans la littérature grammaticale, ou très peu, mais ma compréhension personnelle me semble satisfaisante ; cependant, ce que je déduis est très difficile à exposer, et donc ne peut se résumer à quelques mots. De plus, aussi longue que j'ai cru devoir faire cette exposition elle est loin d'être assez longue pour traiter le sujet  complètement. Ça n'est donc toujours qu'un essentiel. Elle est néanmoins conçue en tenant compte du point de vue de l'étudiant anglophone qui a déjà une certaine facilité avec le français.

On trouve la remarque suivante à l'entrée « [en² pronom atone de la 3e personne](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) ».

> 3.Dans certains cas, en nombre limité, l'antécédent est sous-entendu (implicite) et se dégage de la situation en vertu de l'usage.

L'usage de « en » dans « Où en es-tu ? » est un de ces cas. L'antécédent ne figure pas parmi les mots écrits ou parlés et il est défini d'après le contexte, mais de façon indéterminée, la définition étant limitée à un concept général que le locuteur et les interlocuteurs perçoivent mais n'identifient pas spécifiquement ; ceci explique  que si l'on demande à un français parlant bien français ce que « en » signifie dans ce contexte, il ne pourra presque jamais répondre et s'il y parvient ce sera après avoir réfléchi un moment ; cependant, il identifiera correctement les cas où il faut ce pronom, cela en raison de l'usage, c'est à dire de l'habitude. On peut trouver un peu aberrant que les locuteurs  scolarisés en France ne sachent pas et qu'il n'y ait pas de véritable nécessité qu'ils sachent, alors qu'un étudiant étranger se voit réduit à devoir comprendre les rouages de ce mécanisme ; néanmoins, l'approche différente de ces deux sortes d'apprenant, en particulier si l'apprenant étranger tient à rester méthodique dans son assimilation du français, doit résulter en cet état de chose. Quoi qu'il en soit, il faut quand même considérer que l'étudiant qui se dirige vers le professorat se doit d'acquérir cette sorte d'information, qui ne peut qu'ajouter à sa maitrise de la langue.

« En » est un pronom qui a un antécédent très vague dans ce contexte: il remplace généralement un nom indéterminé mais d'une sorte bien définie ; c'est la sorte des noms qui  riment avec le mot « étape », pris dans le sens figuré de « étape » dans « étape d'un processus », ce processus étant tel que

```
 1) il se déroule sur une période donnée mais pas nécessairement délimitée (donc de très
    nombreuses possibilités de processus),
 2) il comprend des étapes qui lui sont propres, mais  plus ou moins bien définissables.
```

La question est à propos de quelle étape  du processus a été atteinte, et
la réponse,  *si elle est possible selon le même modèle (J'en suis à…, on en est à …, etc.)*, consiste en la stipulation de cette étape.

*Schéma de correspondance*

- Où [EN] est Y (de X) ?
  ○ À laquelle [DES ÉTAPES DU PROCESSUS « X »] est  Y ? (*reformulation idiomatique*)
  ○ Où [DES ÉTAPES DU PROCESSUS « X »] est  Y ? (*reformulation sans correction de la tournure non idiomatique*)

Si X n'a pas été mentionné avant la question, alors, nécessairement, la question doit être « Où [EN] est Y de X ? ».

On voit donc que ce que l'interlocuteur habitué perçoit à travers « en » est la notion d'étape (que l'on rend aussi par « *point* », « *partie* », « *endroit* », « *moment* », etc., mais il perçoit cela sans identifier dans son esprit le mot ou les mots exacts qui conviennent au cas particulier. Accessoirement il perçoit que le verbe « être » est spécialisé à un concept de progression dans le domaine évoqué en connection avec la question.

On voit aussi que l'antécédent est difficile   à construire : La partie « concept de « point »»  (non mentionnée) est extraite de la construction et la partie « processus » est extraite soit du contexte qui précède, soit de la phrase elle-même.

*Quelques processus*

- **projet** (*en tant que processus qui demande des étapes successives*), **évènement, jeu, construction, étude, voyage, partie** (opposant des adversaires) …

Dans ce processus on peut toujours distinguer des repères que l'on peut nommer de diverses façons : **point (de …), stage (de…), stade (de…), endroit, moment**…

*Par exemple*

> ([TLFi, endroit](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/endroit)) B.− P. ext. Partie déterminée
> 3. d'un ouvrage littéraire, religieux, etc.

Ces points, stages, stades et endroits (pour ne nommer que les termes les plus courants) pourront correspondre à des concepts habituels (**début, milieu, fin, partie principale, partie intermédiaire, …**) ou de sorte plus particulière (**étapes difficiles, finition, vérification, préparation,…**). Seulement quelques exemples sont donnés ici, mais l'idée générale est celle de *point* ou d'*endroit*. Un point dans une succession peut être marqué par un élément (**récit de, question de …**), en particulier un élément portant un numéro ou un élément identifié par un adjectif ordinal (**X, Y, …, premier, second, dernier, n° 1, n° 2**, etc.) et aussi par une description (**où** …,) ; seulement quelques possibilités ont été listées. On voit que la catégorie est celle de certains noms indiquant une location dans le sens figuré (dans un processus).

Concernant des évènements de toutes sortes, par exemple des évènements qui opposent deux adversaires (sport de combat, échecs, etc.),  on ne peut pas toujours utiliser cette sorte de question comportant le pronom « en ». Il se peut qu'il n'existe pas d'étapes reconnaissables de l'évènement et alors l'interlocuteur ne comprend pas ce qu'on lui demande. Prenons des exemples.

- *guerre qui bat son plein entre deux pays*
  *Un contemporain d'un troisième pays ne dira pas normalement « Où en sont-ils (de cette guerre) ? », sauf peut-être pour insinuer certaines notions qui dépendront du contexte et que l'on ne peut pas prévoir.*
- *match de boxe*
  — Ils en sont où ?
  — Au troisième round…
  (*Si c'est un match en direct seulement la réponse "Au début" est possible ; si c'est un match que l'on a déjà vu, il ne s'agit plus du même processus et pour des personnes qui ont déjà vu ce match des réponses telles que « À la fin » et « Au milieu du match. » deviennent aussi possibles.*)
- *match de football*
  — Ils en sont où ?
  — Vers la fin de la première mi-temps.
- *partie d'échec*
  Entre personnes qui ne connaissent pas la théorie, "Ils en sont où ?" n'a pas de signification bien définie parce qu'à part le tout début du jeu il n'existe pas de repère comme « milieu du jeu » et « fin du jeu », ces termes n'ont pas de signification. C'est différent pour des joueurs studieux ou professionnels, chez qui les notions d'*ouverture*, *milieu de jeu* et *fin de jeu* correspondent à des étapes assez bien marquées dans une partie ; donc la question sera assez appropriée dans ce second contexte.
- *Des enfants qui jouent dans la cour*
  La question (Où en sont-ils (de leur jeu) ?) n'a pas de sens ; même s'il y a eu un début, la période de jeu est indéfinie et il n'y a pas dans le jeu des étapes qui permettent de l'identifier par ses parties.
- Où en es-tu ((de la **réalisation**/du **développement**) de ton projet) ?
  À quel stade/stage/point (du développement) **de** ton projet es-tu ? (*J'en suis aux préparations.* — *J'en suis au stage/stade des préparations.*)
- Où en es-tu ((de la **lecture**) de ton livre) ?
  À quel endroit/… du livre es-tu ? — *Ici tout nom qui indique un endroit dans un livre  convient : chapitre, page, partie, tome, récit …* — (*J'en suis au récit des prisonniers qui s'échappent en escaladant la falaise.* Le point est mentionné au moyen d'une description.)
- Où en est-elle de sa grossesse ? (*Elle en est au cinquième mois.*)
- Où en est-on de la réforme sur la taxe d'habitation ? ([ref.](https://www.bfmtv.com/societe/ou-en-est-on-de-la-reforme-sur-la-taxe-d-habitation-bfmtv-repond-a-vos-questions_VN-202012090162.html)) (*Dans le cas présent il n'y a pas de repère intrinsèques qui soient applicables à tous les processus de cette sorte, mais pour chaque cas il y a souvent des étapes (en plus ou moins grand nombre) que l'on peut marquer par une description. Il existe une particularité concernant ce type de  réponse : on ne peut pas toujours répondre par « On en est … », « Ils en sont … », …*)
- Confinement : où en est-on ailleurs en Europe ? ([ref.](https://www.liberation.fr/planete/2020/12/13/confinement-ou-en-est-on-ailleurs-en-europe_1808529)) (*remarque précédente*)
- Où en est-on de la réforme sur la taxe d'habitation ?([ref.](https://www.bfmtv.com/societe/ou-en-est-on-de-la-reforme-sur-la-taxe-d-habitation-bfmtv-repond-a-vos-questions_VN-202012090162.html)) (*remarque précédente*)

Considérons maintenant la phrase qui constitue la réponse.

- *Je suis de les premières préparations avec mon projet.*

La formulation correcte est la suivante.

- *J'**en** suis **aux** premières préparations (**de** mon projet).*
  (*Je [**de** les stages de mon projet] suis aux premières préparations  (**de** mon projet).*)

Ce n'est cependant correct que grammaticalement ; il y a un problème de sens : c'est une formulation ambiguë. En réponse à la question « Où en es-tu de ton projet ? » il ne faut pas répéter « de … projet ».

Si on utilise la phrase sans que ce soit une réponse à la question il faut une formulation différente parce que « de » est facilement compris comme préposition introduisant « projet » en tant que complément du nom « préparations », ce qui, de plus parle de préparations différentes : ce ne sont plus des préparations à l'intérieur du projet mais des préparations avant de commencer le projet. Donc, pour  associer « préparations » au processus voulu il faut préciser autrement que par « de » le contexte d'utilisation du mot « projet », ce que l'on peut faire comme suit, par exemple.

- Dans mon projet, je suis aux premières préparations.
- Dans le déroulement de mon projet , je suis aux premières préparations. (*« En  » n'est pas nécessaire.*)

L'idée courante que « de » est associé au pronom « en » reste valide ; la fonction de « de » est ici de marquer une fraction d'une totalité, mais cette totalité est celle des stages et « préparation » n'est qu'un stage parmi d'autres. L'occurrence de « de » dont il est question se trouve ailleurs (voir ci-dessus); c'est la signification que l'on trouve dans des phrases comme la suivante.

- Cette embarcation, de tous les bateaux à voile, est la plus stable.
  De tous les bateaux à voile cette embarcation est la plus stable. (*même sens*)

La raison de l'utilisation de « en » est de rendre spécifique une simple question de location. « Tu es où ? » ne convient pas; ça ne convient pas non plus trop bien en anglais. (For instance: So, you have been studying mathematics…Where are you? — *Il est peu probable que vous disiez ça, ce n'est pas idiomatique en anglais et vous pourriez même vous demander si la question ne concernerait pas une simple information sur une position physique. Vous pourriez dire cependant* « So, you have been studying mathematics…Where are you with your study? » [réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=b9DPi3nulgsC&pg=PA207&dq=%22where+are+you+with+your%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG0rXb4_rtAhVIKBoKHZ-PCKAQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22where%20are%20you%20with%20your%22&f=false). *Cependant, de façon peut-être plus idiomatique, vous diriez* « How far did you get? » En utilisant ces termes il est clair que la formulation est complète, mais « How far have you been? » ne semble pas très idiomatique sans un complément ; il faut utiliser un autre verbe que « to be ».
Il se fait qu'en  français une forme similaire existe, mais il faut changer de termes, d'idées.

- Alors tu as  étudié les mathématiques… Tu es arrivé où ?

Comme cette formulation est acceptable, on voit qu'une quasi correspondance existe et il n'est nul question d'ajouter « en » pour rendre cela correct. Cela montre aussi que l'utilisation de « en » est une question de quelle forme est utilisée, elle rend idiomatique, spécifique, la forme utilisant le verbe « être ». Elle permet de situer le contexte.
En français, si vous dites  "Tu es où ? » l'interlocuteur ne comprend pas autre chose qu'une demande d'*information sur une location spatiale*.  Introduire « en » permet de référer spécifiquement au projet et d'éliminer toute autre possibilité. On dira, bien sûr, que puisque le contexte est concerné par des considérations d'une sorte ou d'une autre à propos d'un projet, il n'y a pas lieu d'ajouter des élément pour insister là-dessus ; ce n'est pas quelque chose que je puisse évaluer, les implications étant multiples et trop complexes.  Ce que l'on peut retenir c'est qu'introduire « en » permet de référer spécifiquement au projet et à des étapes, et d'éliminer toute autre possibilité.

Answer (score 2):

***En être*** forme des locutions verbales qui signifient *être situé* dans une situation/un processus qui évolue.

La question ***T'en es où*** pourra recevoir comme réponses: *j'ai laissé tomber; j'en suis nulle part; je viens de commencer; au début; c'est en cours; j'en ai fait la moitié; j'en suis à la moitié; j'ai fait une pause; j'ai presque fini; j'ai fini hier*, etc.

Si on supprime ***en***, la phrase devient ambiguë :

> T'es où avec ton projet ?

On demande peut-être à quel endroit géographique se situe la personne qui a son projet sous le bras.

Note: *en être **avec*** est la forme la plus courante et la seule possible quand le complément est une personne ou une objet concret (ex: *tu en es où avec ton chef ?*, *tu en es où avec ta nouvelle voiture ?*), dans les autres cas, la préposition ***de*** est souvent plus soutenue et ***avec*** plus familier :

> Tu en es où avec/de ton tour du monde ?
> Tu en es où avec/de ton projet ?
> Tu en es où avec/de ton doctorat ?
> Tu en es où avec/de tes devoirs ?

> Où en êtes-vous de vos lourdes affaires ? J'en suis plus tourmenté
> que de mon propre sort !
> Lamartine, *Souvenirs et Portraits*, 1872

> L’écolier tenta encore un effort. — Frère Claude, donnez-moi au moins un petit parisis pour manger.
> — Où en êtes-vous des décrétales de Gratien ? demanda dom Claude.
> — J’ai perdu mes cahiers.
> — Où en êtes-vous des humanités latines ?
> — On m’a volé mon exemplaire d’Horatius.
> — Où en êtes-vous d’Aristoteles ?
> — Ma foi ! frère, quel est donc ce père de l’église qui dit que les erreurs des hérétiques ont de tout temps eu pour repaire les broussailles de la métaphysique d’Aristoteles ? Foin d’Aristoteles ! je ne veux pas déchirer ma religion à sa métaphysique.
> — Jeune homme, reprit l’archidiacre, il y avait à la dernière entrée du roi un gentilhomme appelé Philippe de Comines, qui portait brodée sur la houssure de son cheval sa devise, que je vous conseille de méditer : *Qui non laborat non manducet*.
> L’écolier resta un moment silencieux, le doigt à l’oreille, l’œil fixé à terre, et la mine fâchée. Tout à coup il se retourna vers Claude avec la vive prestesse d’un hoche-queue.
> — Ainsi, bon frère, vous me refusez un sol parisis pour acheter une croûte chez un talmellier ?
> — *Qui non laborat non manducet*.

Victor Hugo, *Notre Dame de Paris, ἈΝΆΓΚΗ*, 1831

On trouve aussi d'autres prépositions :

> *Tu en es où **dans** ton projet ?*
> *Tu en es où **par rapport** à ton frère ?*

> *Vous ne m'écrivez pas, chers amis ; où en êtes-vous **chez** vous ?*
> George Sand, *Correspondances*, 1892