# « Nous pourrions parler de [nom au féminin + épithète]... Mais nous allons plutôt le/la montrer » : choix du pronom objet direct ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, genre, verbes-de-perception

> — Nous pourrions parler de notre *performance* au sol sans égale
>  (1) —
> Mais nous allons plutôt **le** montrer.
>  (2) — Mais nous allons plutôt **la**
> montrer.

Dans [une vidéo](https://youtu.be/8oFjX0g2VPI?t=12) on fait le choix (1) et j'avais l'impression que ça renvoyait à un antécédent plus générique que la *performance* (n.f.) dont on vient tout juste de parler et je trouvais ça curieux...

À quoi réfère/sert le pronom objet direct (neutre ?) [*le*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/le/1) dans la phrase (1) et son emploi est-il contre-indiqué ou semble-t-il inhabituel avec le nom féminin dans la phrase précédente avec son complément (j'ai lu sommairement LBU14 §671 mais ne sais pas trop quoi en faire) ? Laquelle de ces phrases est la plus claire et usuelle ; l'ajout du complément représenté par *vous* influence-t-il le choix du genre du pronom ; le verbe *montrer* ou l'exemple en question constitue-t-il un cas particulier de choix d'emploi ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'existe pas d'antécédent masculin explicite ou implicite qui tienne (à part « le sol », mais ce n'est visiblement pas ce que veut montrer la vidéo). Je ne vois donc pas comment le masculin pourrait se justifier grammaticalement parlant.

Je pencherait donc pour la faute d'inattention, peut-être simplement due à l'éloignement entre le début et la fin de la phrase, affichées sur des écrans différents. On pourrait appeler ça un accord de « non-[proximité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9) »...

Comment: Montrer _quelque chose_ très généralement ?

Comment: Si on veut. La performance a perdu son genre en perdant son sens précis.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de doute : dans ce qui précède il s'agit de deux concepts, une performance et une possibilité à propos de cette performance, cette dernière étant la possibilité d'en parler. Il y a donc deux choix et on ne peut certainement pas concevoir de montrer la possibilité de parler de la performance. Ce qui va être montré, c'est la performance et les images confirment ce fait. Donc, le pronom « la » est nécessaire, et on doit conclure qu'il y a une erreur. Il faut toujours faire au plus simple : aller chercher ce qui n'a pas été dit encore, comme par exemple « les possibilités de décollage et d'atterrissage sont sans égal » ne fait pas partie du processus linguistique déterminant l'usage du pronom « le ».
Si au lieu de « Nous pourrions parler de notre performance au sol sans égale » nous avions une assertion telle que « Notre performance au sol est  sans égale », alors il y a les deux possibilités: si on choisit la première, l'antécédent de  « le » est « la performance est sans égale » (sans aucun doute). Si la seconde possibilité est choisie, il s'ensuit que ce que l'on va montrer, c'est la performance.

---

Je n'ai pas trouvé d'erreur dans l'explication moins détaillée qui a été proposée en premier. Je ne peux que reprendre l'explication en la détaillant beaucoup plus, ce qui n'est pas gênant comme elle  peut  être utile soit à qui est faible sur ce point particulier de grammaire, soit aux étudiants les plus jeunes.

**A**
Une revue de ce qui importe dans la § 671 (pour se mettre en train)

<sub>Note : Les italiques entre les crochets sont les commentaires de user LPH.</sub>

a) « Le » s'emploie comme forme neutre pour *reprendre* ou *annoncer* une phrase,  [*On doit ajouter « une proposition dépendante », « un syntagme ».*]
Si je vous LE disais pourtant, que **je vous aime** [*« LE » annonce « je vous aime »; dans le cas présent d'antécédent il n'y a pas de difficulté, l'antécédent est représenté par une forme dans le texte.*]
Je voudrais **aller dans un bateau à moteur**, dit-il en voyant Sara. Sara LE lui promit. [*« LE » reprend « aller dans un bateau à moteur », mais attention, la reprise n'est pas de la sorte simple, comme dans le cas précédent; on ne devrait pas dire « reprise » d'une phrase en fait, mais une reprise* à partir *d'une phrase; dans le cas présent la reprise est construite à partir de la phrase: ce que Sara promet ce n'est pas « aller dans un bateau à moteur » mais « il ira dans un bateau à moteur ». Il y a une connection naturelle qui se fait à partir de la sémantique. C'est « promettre » qui détermine l'antécédent, et ce pour tout le monde. Supposons que la seconde phrase ait été « Sara LE lui refusa. »; dans ce second cas l'antécédent est sans problème, il est représenté exactement par la forme (lui refusa **d'aller dans un bateau à moteur**), cela, encore une fois en vertu du sens du verbe « refuser ». Les utilisateur de la langues sont formés à penser de cette manière et tout le monde est d'accord là-dessus. Les grammairiens reconnaissent néanmoins que cette reconstruction de l'antécédent pour les pronoms « le » et « en » n'est pas quelque chose de très net. Qu'il peut exister une différence entre la forme reprise et l'antécédent est mentionné dans la § 671, en dessous des exemple montrant l'usage facultatif de « le ».*]

> On observera que le pronom représente parfois, non le mot (ou le syntagme) tel qu'il a été exprimé, mais l'idée incluse dans ce mot ou, si l'on veut, ce mot adapté à une situation syntaxique différente; dans « Viens chaque fois que tu LE pourras », « le » correspond à  « venir » et non « viens ».

b) Dans certaines expressions, « le », parfois « la » et « les » s'emploient sans antécédent.[*Rien dans « b) » n'est applicable parce que dans « (1) »  le pronom « le » ne fait pas partie d'une expression plus ou moins figée, donc il a un antécédent.*]

**B**

Si on examine tout ce que le texte fournit on trouve qu'il informe

- 1/  que **le locuteur pourrait faire quelque chose**, c'est à dire qu'il informe que le locuteur a une possibilité, la possibilité de parler de sa performance (**Nous avons la possibilité de parler …**)
- 2/  qu'une performance est un des participants du discours.

On examine le cas donné dans la vidéo. Comme « le » a un antécédent, il doit absolument être extrait des élément d'information que le texte fournit. Même dans des cas (rares en tant que format de syntaxe) où l'antécédent du pronom est sous-entendu il ne peut provenir que de déductions à partir du contexte ; voir par exemple « [TLFi,   en² pronom atone de la 3e personne](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)
.

> « 3.Dans certains cas, en nombre limité, l'antécédent est sous-entendu (implicite) et **se dégage de la situation** en vertu de l'usage. »,

Voir cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44091/17649), qui donne un exemple de  comment l'antécédent sous-entendu peut être extrait du contexte.

Il n'y a donc pas d'autre moyen que de déduire l'antécédent de «  1/  » et «  2/  ». Selon le « a) » dans § 671 on peut d'abord supposer que la phrase entière est « reprise » ce qui donne ceci.

- Mais nous allons plutôt  montrer  que nous pourrions parler de notre performance au sol sans égale. (*C'est à dire « Mais nous allons plutôt  montrer le. », « le » étant obligatoirement le pronom neutre.*) On voit bien que cela ne peut pas être un choix intelligent, ça n'a aucun intérêt dans la discussion; donc on rejette ce cas et « le » doit reprendre autre chose. Comme il n'y a rien d'autre à reprendre que « notre performance au sol sans égale » et que chose très importante, une performance est bien quelque chose que l'on peut monter, il faut que ce soit l'antécédent ; comme le genre de ce syntagme nominal antécédent est féminin, il faut la forme féminine du pronom, « la » ; en d'autres mots, il y a une erreur. Qu'est-ce que l'on pourrait montrer d'autre qui se trouve dans le contexte ? Rien, d'après mes conclusions.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Évidemment, lorsque (dans l'hypothèse du dernier alinéa) on utilise « le » on montre la supériorité par la performance elle-même et donc c'est comme pour la possibilité « la », c'est toujours montrer la performance, mais on rentre dans des considérations compliquées à partir de cette constatation et c'est peut-être devenir trop pointilleux.

Comment: Bof, disons que je tournais autour du pot parce que j'aimerais lire aussi d'autres réponses, mais je peux imaginer que _le_ c'est simplement _quelque chose_ et ça c'est masculin ou neutre. C'est aussi pour ça que je parle d'antécédent plus générique... Ce qui explique que j'avais de la difficulté à comprendre la « possibilité ». Je trouve que plus généralement on _montre_ « quelque chose » et non une « possibilité ». En effet, le verbe de la phrase dans laquelle apparaît le pronom c'est la phrase avec le verbe _montrer_ et non avec _pouvoir_

Comment: Mais la réflexion continue. Peut-être que pour globalement l'ensemble de la phrase qui précède on emploie le neutre, et qu'avec la _performance_, le féminin ? En fait j'aimerais mieux comprendre ce que constitue la phrase qui précède et ses éléments, pour la phrase qui suit, la qualifier. Le tout est peut-être un peu obscur mais 671 et ss. c'est passablement élaboré.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Je vois que l'on ne se comprend toujours pas. Je vais réviser ça et essayer de voir si je n'aurais pas fait d'erreur, sinon si je ne pourrais pas être plus clair. Ça prendra un peu de temps.

Comment: J'ai lu. J'interprète certaines choses différemment ce qui fait que c'est l'application qui donne un résultat différent mais merci d'avoir expliqué ! Je reste toujours réticent à accepter l'idée de possibilité que tu développes en B. Je vais peut-être répondre mais je n'ai pas ton endurance pour écrire de longs textes qui restent assez inaccessibles à mon avis.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Je comprends bien la réticence générale à avoir recours à de longs texte, mais en France, du moins du temps de mes études, on ne parlait jamais d'une dissertation trop longue et plutôt d'une dissertation qui ne traite pas le sujet.

Answer (score 0):

> Montrer que la performance au sol est sans égale. (démontrer)
>  Montrer une performance au sol sans égale. (faire
> voir)

Dans le premier cas que l'on a remanié, on montre quelque chose dont le genre ne saurait être féminin, que ce soit analysé comme neutre ou comme [*quelque chose*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2644), justement. On pense que l'on voulait démontrer plus que de faire voir...

Comment: Un début de réponse...

Comment: C'est _plus que ne_ ou _plus que de_  ou les deux ?

Comment: AMHA, *que ne faire voir* ou alors *on pense qu'il s'agissait plus de démontrer que de faire voir*.